# Standard errors in R, package emmeans

Tags: standard-error, multinomial-logit, delta-method, back-transformation

I am fitting a multinomial logit model in R by using the `multinom()` function in the nnet package. I would like to retreive the proportions in each class for the two groups. If I use the package emmeans to do so I get the results, as reported below. If I use the delta method from package car I get the same back-transformed proportions, but different standard errors. I am not able to understand the reason for such a difference.

```
##########################################################################
#load data
rm(list=ls())
freq <- c(21, 23, 17, 24, 19, 13, 34, 23, 21, 26, 29, 40, 37, 31, 23,
           32, 32, 22, 29, 28, 28, 33, 20, 34, 42, 45, 40, 42, 16, 7, 16,
           13, 28, 27, 25, 19, 33, 40, 37, 36, 47, 18, 20, 13, 12, 13, 13, 
           12, 40, 22, 33, 30, 15, 11, 8, 10, 26, 27, 21, 22, 30, 24, 31,
           30, 28, 25, 27, 21, 16, 24, 13, 8, 29, 12, 18, 8, 8, 4, 5, 4, 8,
           14, 16, 7, 27, 20, 13, 5, 20, 22, 14, 17, 13, 12, 20, 19, 14, 10,
           8, 3, 3, 10, 9, 1, 8, 8, 7, 10, 19, 15, 19, 20, 20, 13, 18, 11,
           21, 26, 22, 16)
Group <- rep(c("P1", "P2"), each = 12, length.out = length(freq))
Class <- rep( paste("c", 1:5, sep = ""), each=24)

datasetR <- data.frame(
  Photo = rep(rep(1:24, 5), times = freq), 
  Group = rep(Group, times = freq),
  Class = rep(paste("c", 1:5, sep = ""), times = c(639, 614, 542, 335, 311)) )
rm(freq, Group)

#Fit multinomial model
library(nnet)
mmod <- multinom(Class ~ Group, data=datasetR)

#Calculate proportions
emmeans::emmeans(mmod, ~Class|Group, mode="prob")

#Use delta method to derive standard errors
library(car)
coefs <- as.vector(coef(mmod))
names(coefs) <- paste("b", 1:8, sep="")
vcovMmod <- vcov(mmod)
p1 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="1/(1+(exp(b1)+exp(b2)+exp(b3)+exp(b4)))",  vcov.=vcovMmod)
p2 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b1)/(1+(exp(b1)+exp(b2)+exp(b3)+exp(b4)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)
p3 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b2)/(1+(exp(b1)+exp(b2)+exp(b3)+exp(b4)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)
p4 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b3)/(1+(exp(b1)+exp(b2)+exp(b3)+exp(b4)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)
p5 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b4)/(1+(exp(b1)+exp(b2)+exp(b3)+exp(b4)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)
p6 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(0)/(1+(exp(b1 +b5)+exp(b2+b6)+exp(b3+b7)+exp(b4+b8)))",  vcov.=vcovMmod)
p7 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b1+b5)/(1+(exp(b1+b5)+exp(b2+b6)+exp(b3+b7)+exp(b4+b8)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)
p8 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b2+b6)/(1+(exp(b1+b5)+exp(b2+b6)+exp(b3+b7)+exp(b4+b8)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)
p9 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b3+b7)/(1+(exp(b1+b5)+exp(b2+b6)+exp(b3+b7)+exp(b4+b8)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)

p10 <- deltaMethod(coefs, g="exp(b4+b8)/(1+(exp(b1+b5)+exp(b2+b6)+exp(b3+b7)+exp(b4+b8)))", vcov.=vcovMmod)
result <- rbind(p1=p1,p2=p2,p3=p3,p4=p4,p5=p5,p6=p6,p7=p7,p8=p8,p9=p9,p10=p10)
result
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I do note that the emmeans SEs are proportional to `sqrt(prob*(1-prob))` within each group:

```
> x = summary(emmeans(mmod, ~Class|Group, mode="prob"))
> with(x, sqrt(prob*(1-prob)) / SE)
 [1] 33.15117 33.15117 33.15117 33.15117 33.15117 
 [6] 36.63332 36.63332 36.63332 36.63332 36.63332
```

This seems, intuitively, like it might be correct.

#### Addendum

I am going to say further that I am certain that the SEs from `emmeans` are the correct ones. This is a simple dataset having 2 groups, and proportions of each category in each group. Note these results:

```
> sum(datasetR$Group == "P1")
[1] 1099
> sqrt(.Last.value)
[1] 33.15117

> sum(datasetR$Group == "P2")
[1] 1342
> sqrt(.Last.value)
[1] 36.63332
```

Compare these with the results I showed earlier. Here are hand calculations of the first estimate and SE:

```
> sum((datasetR$Group == "P1") & (datasetR$Class == "c1"))
[1] 290

> ( p11 = 290 / 1099 )
[1] 0.2638763

> sqrt(p11 * (1 - p11) / 1099)
[1] 0.01329464
```

Compare with:

```
> emmeans::emmeans(mmod, ~Class|Group, mode="prob")
Group = P1:
 Class       prob          SE df   lower.CL  upper.CL
 c1    0.26387376 0.013294604  8 0.23321635 0.2945312
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. So, it would seem that the delta method should not be used to derive proportions from a multinomial fit. I am wondering why. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Emmeans uses the delta method! So it is not the method itself that’s the issue. I am not sure what went wrong in the deltaMethod function, but it appears there is a bug somewhere.